# Get ajax result in foreach

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I try to load data from service yelp, no problem with the request, but I can't push it to array and return it. 
I need to get ajax result in every iteration.
How to stop it until ajax result has received?

can anyone help me?

```js
this.getDataForPlaces = function(addresses){
 var locationDescs = [];
 _.each(addresses, function(address){
  var promise = getLocationDesc(address).then(function(data) {
          locationDescs.push(data);
    });
 })

 return locationDescs;
};



var getLocationDesc = function(address){

   var parameters = [];
            
            var message = {
                'action' : 'http://api.yelp.com/v2/search',
                'method' : 'GET',
                'parameters' : parameters
            };

            OAuth.setTimestampAndNonce(message);
            OAuth.SignatureMethod.sign(message, accessor);

            var parameterMap = OAuth.getParameterMap(message.parameters);
            return $.ajax({
                'url' : message.action,
                'cache': true,
                'method':message.method,
                'data' : parameterMap,
                'dataType' : 'jsonp',
                'jsonp' : 'callback',
                'success':function(data){
                 console.log(data);
                }
            });
 };
```

Comment: Don't return complete ajax function , just inside the `success` function of ajax return the `data`  like this : `return data;` because return whole ajax function it is not an data that you are getting from services , you have to return data variable. check my answer to your question for example.

Comment: @Arsh Ajax in pending state while foreach works, how to stop iteration till ajax receive the value?

Comment: Please do check my answer to see how you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the `data` variable instead of `ajax` function like this : replace the following

```
return $.ajax({
                'url' : message.action,
                'cache': true,
                'method':message.method,
                'data' : parameterMap,
                'dataType' : 'jsonp',
                'jsonp' : 'callback',
                'success':function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
```

with

```
$.ajax({
                'url' : message.action,
                'cache': true,
                'method':message.method,
                'data' : parameterMap,
                'dataType' : 'jsonp',
                'jsonp' : 'callback',
                'success':function(data){
                    return data;
                }
            });
```

for pausing / stoping the loop until the ajax request completes you can replace the following :

```
var promise = getLocationDesc(address).then(function(data) {
                locationDescs.push(data);
          });
```

with

```
var promise = $.when(getLocationDesc(address)).done(function(data){
   locationDescs.push(data);
});
```

if above does not work then use the following and replace the whole loop with following

```
var locationDescs = [];
    _.each(addresses, function(address){
                locationDescs.push(getLocationDesc(address));
    });
$.when.apply($,locationDescs).done(function(){ 
});
```

Don't return complete ajax function , just inside the `success` function of ajax return the `data`  like this : `return data;` because return whole ajax function it is not an data that you are getting from services , you have to return data variable.

Comment: anyway, data is undefined.

Comment: Did you use : return data; inside ajax ? And where do you get undefined data ?

Comment: @PavelPavel where you are getting undefined data ? inside when ? or inside ajax ?

Comment: I get undefined inside "when", because ajax request in pending state when I return from the function;

Comment: @PavelPavel do look at my answer and use the updated part for loop